# vector allocation error subscript to pointer to incomplete type

Tags: c, arrays

i have my product

```
typedef struct proditem *prodItem;
```

and i have a symbol table of products

```
typedef struct tabp *tabP;
struct tabp {
    prodItem vettP;
    int nP;
};
```

i need to allocate in memory,
then :

```
tab->nP = max; // quantity of products
tab->vettP = malloc(max * sizeof(*prodItem));
```

but if a try to use the vector tab->vettP have the error:

`tab->vettP[i]` <<-- subscript to pointer to incomplete type

can anyone help me?

Comment: And what is `struct prodItem`? You typedef a `struct` as `pointer`.

Comment: Are all this code in the same file? Including `struct prodItem` - to me it sounds as if `struct prodItem` isn't known when you have the code `tab->vettP[i]`

Comment: Typedef pointer is a bad idea: my personal opinion. BTW `tab->vettP = malloc(max * sizeof(*prodItem));` should be `tab->vettP = malloc(max * sizeof(struct proditem));`

Comment: For the same explanation written in the form of answer I got an unexplained DV. I'll keep my answer deleted for as long as OP doesn't provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), @LPs

Comment: @user3078414 Probably Someone DV because of that it isn't the answer to the question. It is surely an error but not the one that causes _..pointer to incomplete type_. This type of error can be explained with `struct proditem` posted only. Otherwise we are only guessing and bettng. ;)

Comment: Sure, @LPs, this must be the right direction: without a MCVE, helper's altruism is only a matter of (educated) guessing. (-:

Comment: no @LPs you not require prodItem details because in a ADP you have only to know that this is a pointer

Comment: As required posting a MCVE we can help you. Otherwise it is a waste of time only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved myself, missing a pointer *

```
typedef struct tabp *tabP;
struct tabp {
    prodItem *vettP;
    int nP;
};
```

Product item.h:

```
#ifndef prodItem_h
#define prodItem_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct proditem *prodItem;
typedef char* prodKey ;

prodItem prodItemScan(FILE*);
void prodItemShow(FILE*, prodItem);
int prodItemCheckVoid(prodItem);
void prodItemFree(prodItem);
int prodItemGreater(prodItem,prodItem);

prodKey prodKeyGet(prodItem);
int prodKeyComp(prodKey, prodKey);
#endif /* prodItem_h */
```

symbol table.h

```
#ifndef tabP_h
#define tabP_h

#include <stdio.h>
#include "proditem.h"

typedef struct tabp *tabP;

tabP tabPScan(FILE*);
void tabPShow(FILE*,tabP);

void tabPFree(tabP);
int tabPCount(tabP);
int tabPSearch(tabP, prodKey);

#endif /* tabP_h */
```

symbol table.c

```
#include "tabP.h"

struct tabp {
    prodItem *vettP;
    int nP;
};

tabP tabPScan(FILE *f) {
    int max;
    fscanf(f,"%d", &max);
    tabP tab = malloc((sizeof(*tab)));
    tab->nP = max;
    tab->vettP = malloc(max * sizeof(prodItem));

    for(int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        tab->vettP[i] = prodItemScan(f);

    }

    return tab;
}

void tabPShow(FILE *f, tabP tab){
    for(int i=0; i<tab->nP; i++) {
        prodItemShow(f, tab->vettP[i]);
    }
}

int tabPCount(tabP tab) {
    return tab->nP;
}

int tabPSearch(tabP tab, prodKey key) {
    for (int i=0; i<tab->nP; i++) {
        if (prodKeyComp( prodKeyGet(tab->vettP[i]), key)==1){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Are u sure? Now you have a pointer of pointer. Nothing related to the error you posted...

Comment: yes, i'll update the post with all the code

Comment: Be wary of `typedef`ing pointers. As LPs pointed out, they generally cause more problems by obscuring the level of indirection than they ever solve by saving typing.